# Add Input to mat-table datasource object

Tags: angular, input, angular-material-table

I have a problem.
I'm trying to add input fields to mat-table but I'm having trouble. Attached is a Stackblitz link where I tried to recreate it.
Unfortunately, I can't get along with the similar questions here in Stackoverflow.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkxlgt

I'm grateful for any help or hints.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution.
need to update the formarray every time i push a new object.
i fixed the function:

```
    addLocation(value: any) {
    let location: any = this.locations.find((res) => res.street == value);
    if (this.locationsPicked.indexOf(location) === -1) {
      this.locationsPicked.push(location);
      this.formArray.push(
        new FormGroup({
          price: new FormControl(''),
          select: new FormControl(false),
        })
      );
    }
    this.locationsCtrl.setValue('');
    this.dataSource.data = this.locationsPicked;
  }
```

PS:
i improved my stackblitz example with the solution
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkxlgt